# Attach a file in email from Content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-builder, emailfileattachment

Is there anyway that I can attach af file from Content builder in Salesforce marketing cloud?

I want the file to be added to the email like it would do, if you dragged a file into outlook or any other mail clients.

So far I am only able to attach a link to a document which I have uploaded in the Content Builder.

Comment: You have to enable the functionality. Consider the points shared in this link to the documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_attachments.htm&type=5

Comment: For your information, this functionality is paid. You'll have to pay before it being activated on the backend by SFMC's support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to first ask support to turn it on:

> Contact your account representative to have this feature enabled for
>   your account. You must be familiar with AMPscript to send emails with
>   attachments.

Here is the whole description: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_attachments.htm&type=5

You will need to use this AMPscript function in order to attach a file: [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm)

Here's a nice example of this function used to attach a file from Content Builder from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/):

```
%%[

var @customerKey, @fileAlias
set @customerKey = "LoyaltyMembersCB"
set @fileAlias = "LoyaltyMembers_ContentBuilder.zip"

AttachFile("ContentBuilder", @customerKey, @fileAlias)

]%%
```